# Simple logarithmic question (fundamentals)

Tags: analysis, logarithms, asymptotics

I'm studying Asymptotic Analysis and I need to refresh the log functions, so on this particular case:

$(log\ N)^3$ what would that be equal to? is it:

$log^3(N)$ ?   which would be $log(log(log(N)))$ right? I'm a little confused... lol

In case someone knows:

Why $f(N) = N! + 2^n$ the upper bound using Big O is: $O(N^n)$ ?

isn't N! in the long run greater than $2^n$? and why is it $n^n$ and not $2^n$?

Thank you

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for typesetting

Comment: $(log N)^3$ is the written, equivalently, as $log^3(N)$.

Comment: $$log^{3}(N) = \big(log(N)\big)^{3}$$

Comment: Also, $N^n$ is an upper bound on both, $N!$, and $2^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\log(N)^3$ is exactly what it appears to be: the cube of the logarithm of $N$. However, you are right to note that $\log^3(N)$ is ambiguous. The convention is that $\log^3(N) = \log(N)^3$, but it would be more consistent mathematically to have it mean $\log(\log(\log(N)))$. But it's convention that matters, so $\log^3(N) = \log(N)^3$. (And of course none of these should be confused with $\log(N^3)$.)

Your factorial question is kind of unrelated, but Stirling's approximation tells us that $n! \approx (n/e)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$. This dominates all exponential functions, but grows slower than $n^n$. So $n! = O(n^n)$ is true, but $n! = O(a^n)$ is false for all $a$.

Comment: thank you very much, one more thing before closing it, so

log^3(N)=log(N)^3 and we can say that it's the same as:
3log(N) right?

Then what about:  log(N^3) ? there is no way to separete the exponent right?

Comment: No.  It is $\log(N^3)$ that is equal to $3 \log N$.  The expression $\log(N)^3$ does not simplify further.

Comment: thank you very much, with that info I have #1 of the exam correct for sure :)